# WSO2 esb and api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

we want to use Wso2 api manager and wso2 esb both but we want to use single analytics for both of them and we want both of these products to use the same identity server can it be done i just want to know that.

Comment: Yes, take a look to the official doc [WSO2 Clustering and Deployment Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x)

Answer (score 0):

> we want to use Wso2 api manager and wso2 esb both but we want to use single analytics for both of them

You can configure wso2sp as analytics for both wso2am and wso2ei (esb)

https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/97567378

> we want both of these products to use the same identity server 
>   can it be done i just want to know that.

Yes, it can be done. You can use wso2is as a key manager for wso2am or as an external IdP.